# keyInvalid Error when calling Google Calendar API

Tags: google-api, aws-lambda, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I'm writing a Lambda function that queries Google Calendar events. Although I successfully created a credential (client ID, and client secret) on Google Developers Console, I cannot access the events. Error:

> { "error": { "errors": [{ "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "keyInvalid", "message": "Bad Request" } ], "code": 400, "message": "Bad Request" } }

My http request looks like this:
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/MY_CLIENT_ID/events?key=MY_CLIENT_SECRET

What went wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: where do you have this url from? The client id and secret go into HTTP headers, not into the url.

Comment: see e.g. [this quick example](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python) for a basic python implementation

Answer (score 1):

> "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "keyInvalid", "message": "Bad Request"

Means that the key you are sending is an invalid api key.

**Background info**

When you make a request to a Google api for public data you can use an API key.  Public data is data that is not owned by a user.  For example public posts on google+, google books.  In these instances you can use an api key inorder to access the api using

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=25&q=surfing&type=test&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

key identifies your application to google using the api key you create in google developer console.

Private data is data that is owned by a user for instance your google calendar an application can not post to it with out permissions.  Inorder to do this we use [Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).  You create a client on google developer console then login the user using oauth2.  you will get an access token back then you can make a request

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/MY_CLIENT_ID/events?accesstoken=ACCESSTOKEN
```

Notice that the first request used key and the second used accesstoken.

**Anwser**

Your problem is that you are sending a client secret as an api key which will not work because first of all a client secret is not an api key and second events are private user data which will require that you authenticate your user first.