# Hoe to fix google calendar api of browser quickstart?

Tags: javascript, api, browser, calendar, google-calendar-api

I go through the google calendar api from the browser (https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js). And I got the error message of KeyInvalid,

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "usageLimits",
        "reason": "keyInvalid",
        "message": "Bad Request"
      }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Bad Request"
  }
}
```

The credential is followed:

```
Client ID:
1046277470516-1at2v7e62v1f2oegqgkodvnbqcg81jlm.apps.googleusercontent.com

Client secret:
Ey0M3G9JTihM1EHfjjPREiz1
```

Authorised JavaScript origins:

```
http://localhost    
http://127.0.0.1
```

according to the document, I only change the `CLIENT_ID` and `API_KEY`, the `API_KEY` is equal to the Client Secret above.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the 400 bad request you have encountered,

> "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "keyInvalid", "message": "Bad
>   Request"

It means that the key you are sending is an invalid api key.

I think your problem is similar to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48745939/keyinvalid-error-when-calling-google-calendar-api) wherein you were sending a client secret as an api key which will not work because first of all a client secret is not an api key and second events are private user data which will require that you authenticate your user first.